# Zend: Submit form with uppercase values

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms

I want to submit a zend form but with lowercase values. Whatever user use case but I want to get form value as lowercase. I  am creating form like this.

```
$elements = array();

$element = $this->CreateElement('text', 'LastName');
$element->setLabel('Last Name');
$element->addFilter( 'StringToLower' );
$elements[] = $element;

$element = $this->CreateElement('text', 'FirstName');
$element->setLabel('First Name');
$element->addFilter( 'StringToLower' );
$elements[] = $element;

$this->addElements($elements);
```

And getting values like this:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$values = $request->getParams();
```

Above form is submit form values successfully but `$element->addFilter( 'StringToLower' );` does not seem to work. It always submit the form with user entered case not lowercase.

**How can I force the form to convert all values to lowercase?**

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not describe how you get the result values, but this is the right way to do that:

```
$values = $form->getValues()
```

Also, the more handy way of writing the same code could be:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'LastName', array(
    'label' => 'Last Name',
    'filters' => array('StringToLower')
));
```

And one of the possible complete workarounds could be:

```
if ($this->_request->isPost() && $form->isValid($this->_request->getPost())) {
    $values = $form->getValues();
}
```

Comment: I have edited by question that I am getting values after submitting a form. Actually I am getting request params.

Comment: "Actually I am getting request params." --- you **should** get the values from the form.

Comment: Thanks. Its working by getting values from $form after `isValid()` and `isPOst()` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling $form->isValid() then using $form->getValues()?

The form data wont filter itself unless you have client-side validation/filtering as well.

```
$form = new MyForm();

if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()){
    $filteredValues = $form->getValues();
} else {
    // validation failed
}
```

Comment: yes I am doing `$form->isValid()` but then getting values from request. I have editied by question that how I am getting form values.

Comment: Please review my code snippet for retrieving the filtered values... $form->getValues()

Comment: Go to http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.quickstart.html and go about half way down the page and look for a section called: Check if a form is valid

Comment: Yes, You have a right point. Thanks for helping. I found out the error using both answers. So first post is accepted. Already a +1 for you.